# Switching Frame in Selenium Webdriver, C#

Tags: selenium, webdriver, frames

I am getting this error using Selenium:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: '[JavaScript Error: "a is null" {file: "file:///C:/Users/jzhu/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1925480623.webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js" line: 7509}]' when calling method: [nsICommandProcessor::execute]

Here is my code for this part:

ffbrowser.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[4]/a")).Click();

```
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);

                            ffbrowser.SwitchTo().Frame("content");

                            Thread.Sleep(1000);

                            ffbrowser.SwitchTo().Frame("NavBar");

                            Thread.Sleep(500);

                            ffbrowser.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[12]/a/div/img")).Click();

                            Thread.Sleep(800);

                            InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);

                            Thread.Sleep(2000);

                            InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry(@"Tostring.pdf");

                            Thread.Sleep(1500);

                            InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);

                            Thread.Sleep(3500);

                            //ffbrowser.Navigate().Refresh();

                            //ffbrowser.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();


                            ffbrowser.Navigate().Back();
                            //InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.BROWSER_BACK);

                            Thread.Sleep(1000);

                            InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);

                            Thread.Sleep(1000);

                            InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);

                            Thread.Sleep(500);

                            //Thread.Sleep(500);

                            //ffbrowser.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

                            //Thread.Sleep(1000);

                            //ffbrowser.SwitchTo().Frame("content");

                            //ffbrowser.SwitchTo().Frame("leftnav");

                            //Thread.Sleep(1000);

                            //ffbrowser.FindElement(By.LinkText("My Bills")).Click();

                            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

It is on a website behind a login, so I can't provide the actual example without giving sensitive login information. But I am using switchTo to get inside a frame, then I need to do Navigate.Back(), but it crashes with that error when I try to navigate.

Comment: What code are you using? What browser? What version of that browser? What version of Selenium? What stack trace do you have?

Answer (score 2):

I have very limited knowledge about C#, but I do know that there are errors thrown in other bindings (like Java and Ruby) if you try to call methods on the WebDriver object while inside an iframe object.

The solution is to use the `webdriver.switchTo().defaultContent()` method before attempting to `webdriver.Navigate.Back()`.

Comment: Thanks bgoad, I do have webdriver.switchTo().defaultContent()  But I got the same error message at swtich to default content.

Comment: Looks like you are attempting to call `webdriver.executeScript` somewhere in your code. Can you please update the question with your code, including this line, and your lines to switch in and out of the iframe, as well as the Navigate.Back() line?

Comment: bgoad, I updated my question with part of my code.  You may notice I have two switch to frame before I get to this point.  Any idea?